# How can I force Dark theme on menu bar?

Tags: menu-bar, themes, dark-mode

I am using `macOS Monterey 12.3`.
From `Desktop & Screen Saver` => `Desktop` I have selected `Dark (Still)` under `Big Sur`.

[image]

When I reboot the machine menu bar color is always `light`, as light blue, hence dark-theme is not applied to the menu bar:

[image]

---

From `Desktop & Screen Saver` => `Desktop` after each reboot I have to re-select `Dark (Still)` to apply dark color on the top bar as:

[image]

After each reboot, is it possible to force `Dark (Still)` to take place on the menu bar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The menu bar colour is not controlled from that page of System Preferences.

Try the General page

The first option is between Light, Dark and Auto.

Choose Dark.

Comment: `Dark` is already choosen but it does not have any affect on the top Apple Menu Bar. When you toggle between Light, Dark, and Auto you will see that there will be no color change on the menu bar.

Comment: On Monterey it chnages from Dark Grey background to White in changing from Dark to Light (and also works on Mojave except no Auto) However I don't see the option you have in Desktop

Comment: Interesting it changes opened windows menu bar color only. Please note that I am using `macOS Monterey `. but under Desktop `Big Sur` option exist

Comment: Now I am counfused. There is only one menu bar so if you say "opened windows menu ba" what other menu bar do you have?

Comment: In my question I refer to the top menu bar. When I make changes on your answer, only the top part where (red yellow green circles located on top left corner) of each opened application's color changes. But Apple's menu bar color remains unchanged

Comment: And for me the menu bar and the application's window both chnage (note the top of an Application Window is not a menu bar in macOS - it is in MS Windows and many Unix window managers - there are exceptions e.g. Jav apps)

Comment: Ah :-( Is there anything I can do make this changes from terminal as well? Seems like something is wrongly setup on my macOS.